Error :"subprocess-exited-with-error" on CTFD Repo
When I run serve.py in the CTFD it tells me I need to install pybluemonday module on Python :
Now when I do pip install pybluemonday it gives me this problem :
[tag:> PS C:\Users\elharam4\Desktop\php\ProjectNoteSave.venv\CTFd-master> pip install pybluemonday --no-build-isolat

Collecting pybluemonday
Using cached pybluemonday-0.0.12.tar.gz (8.4 kB)
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
exit code: 1
[26 lines of output]
uname_result(system='Windows', node='DESKTOP-8UI3TJC', release='10', version='10.0.17763', machine='AMD6
4')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\elharam4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyprojec
t_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\elharam4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyprojec
t_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 335, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])

File "C:\Users\elharam4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pyprojec
t_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 149, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)

File "C:\Users\elharam4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_met
a.py", line 366, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
self.run_setup()
File "C:\Users\elharam4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_met
a.py", line 487, in run_setup
super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
File "C:\Users\elharam4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_met
a.py", line 311, in run_setup
exec(code, locals())
File "<string>", line 34, in <module>
File "C:\Users\elharam4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 389, in call
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:

>                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "C:\Users\elharam4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __in
it__
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "C:\Users\elharam4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _exe
cute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,

>                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.
See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.]

and I tried with many things like make an upgrade and install tools python setup and tried the --pre and --no-build-isolation. Does anyone know how to fix ?
This Is The Repo :

https://github.com/CTFd/CTFd

